# Problema con authenticate(username=username, password=password) en django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, djangorestframework, tokens

Estoy intentando hacer un login para una api con django rest framework, me estoy guiando con este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8Sz2mF0ENU

Aqui está solo el código que utilizo en la vista login:

pedidos/urls:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('usuarios', views.UsuarioViewSet)
router.register('tecnicos', views.TecnicoViewSet)
router.register('pedidos', views.PedidoViewSet)
router.register('mispedidos', views.PedidoMiUsuarioSet)
router.register('registrar', views.Registrar, base_name = 'registro')
router.register('login', views.LoginView, base_name = 'login')
router.register('logout', views.LogoutView, base_name = 'logout')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

views.py:

```
class LoginView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data["user"]
        django_login(request, user)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({"token": token.key}, status=200)
```

serializers.py:

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get("username", "")
        email = data.get("email", "")
        password = data.get("password", "")
        print(password)
        print(email)
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    data["user"] = user
                else:
                    msg = "Usuario desactivado"
                    raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
            else:
                msg = "Imposible loguear con los parametros dados"
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = "Se necesita el username y password"
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        return data
```

Básicamente el en el serializador del Login, cuando llega a la línea de
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
no es válido y va por el camino del else mostrando el error "Imposible loguear con los parámetros dados"

No se que error estoy cometiendo para que no funcione el "authenticate".

Comment: podrias hacer un print de username y password antes del if user: ...

Comment: para ver que esta trayendo y comparar con tu bd si son los correctos o no

Comment: me llegan ambos datos, pero debajo de "if user:" puedo obtener user.username, pero no user.password

Answer (score 1):

Al final descubrí el problema, resulta que los ViewSets el método post en realidad se llama create, por lo que lo correcto era:

```
class LoginView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data["user"]
        django_login(request, user)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({"token": token.key}, status=200)
```